# Is there ever a requirement to change the limits of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I don't have issues with doing integration problems, but occasionally I see the solution changing the limits of integration whenever a $u$-substitution is done.

I obviously don't have a problem doing this, and I just recently noticed my book doing this under the chapter involving "area of surface of revolution."

My question is did I develop a bad habit by never changing the limits of integration, or is it a best practice to always change limits of integration?

My teacher said on a test, and in general, if we do not change the limits of integration then we should be signifying this by labeling our limits of integration $x=$ lower-limit and $x=$upper-limit.

**EDIT EXAMPLE INCLUDED**

After further investigation, my confusion is because of the two below equations:

`Find the exact area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the x-axis`
$$y=\sqrt{1+4x}, 1\le x\le 5$$

The limits of integration were changed in the solution to this problem.

`The given curve is rotated about the y-axis.  Find the area of the resulting surface.`
$$y=x^\frac{1}{3}, 1\le y \le 2$$

The limits of integration were NOT changed in the solution to this problem.

Comment: If you never got a result wrong by not changing the limits of integration, you should gamble, gamble a lot.

Comment: Your teacher is right, forgetting about changing the limits of integration is a frequent source of error. You usually have two choices: (i) Find an antiderivative in terms of $u$, replace $u$ by what it is in terms of $x$, then use the old limits or (ii) Put the limits in terms of $u$, and never go back to $x$. Do one or the other, don't "mix." In general I prefer (ii). Your teacher's advice, writing $x=a$ or $u=c$  will help you keep track, and will prevent error.

Comment: @GitGud that's exactly what prompted this question.  I got a result that was different than the solution, but I'm not sure if it is wrong.  The only difference is that I didn't change my limits of integration.

Comment: @inquisitor It is wrong in general. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Relation_to_the_fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: @inquisitor : There are _some_ situations in which changing the bounds is not optional.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes we are doing an indefinite integral by $u$-substitution, and then the form of integral involving $u$ is easily converted back into $x$ or whatever the original variable was at the end of the process.

However when a definite integral is involved, you have a choice of either converting the limits of integration from (say) $x$ limits to $u$ limits, or considering the $u$-substitution as a means to obtaining the final indefinite integral in terms of $x$ and using the original limits of integration.

The former has the advantage of skipping the substitution back into $x$, but at the cost of figuring out how to change the limits of integration into terms of $u$.  This was a bad habit you learned, or more precisely, a useful habit you failed to learn.  Converting the limits from $x$ to $u$ is ordinarily just a matter of using the $x$ limits in the expression for $u$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  What troubles me is early in our learning integration, the book seemed to indicate a choice as to using the substituted limits of integration, so I just did what I learned first.  I'm going to try and break myself out of this habit.

Comment: I would add that (1) not changing the bounds often makes the problem appear more complicated than it really is, and (2) in some instances, like the second example in my answer posted here, changing the bounds may be absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

**The idea is that the limits of the integral are in terms of the variable of integration.** So take for instance:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx
$$
Notice that our function is periodic with period $2\pi$ and symmetric about its half period point, $\pi$; therefore,
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx
$$
This will be important when we make the $u$-substitution. In this case, we might choose $u=\cos(x)$ with $du=-\sin(x)dx$; therefore,
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx\\=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx=-2\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{e^{u}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{u}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du
$$
You'll notice a few things about this process. First, if I had left the limits of integration as $0$ to $\pi$ after making the $u$-substitution, then the two integrals would have been different since the functions being integrated over would have been different.  Remember, the integration variable is a **dummy variable**, so what you use for it is completely irrelevant. Thus,
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(u)e^{\cos u}du
$$
Second, the way you decide how the limits change is by evaluating the parameterization equation. So for the above example $u(x)=\cos(x)$ so $u(0)=1$ and $u(\pi)=-1$. If I had left the limits as $0$ and $2\pi$, then the $u$-integral would have been from $1$ to $1$ which is obviously wrong since it evaluates to $0$ and the [graph of our function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos(x)*e%5E(cos(x)),+0%3Cx%3C2pi) clearly has a net positive area over the interval.

**Edit:** As Barry Cipra alludes to in the comments, there is a neat explanation for why the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ causes problems when the variable changes. Specifically, I used the following identities in the above calculations
$$
\cos(x)=u\\
\sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}\\
\therefore \ -\sin(x)=-\sqrt{1-u^2}
$$
But this is not always true. The second line comes from $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, which means that you have to take a square root. And whenever a square root is introduced so too must a plus-or-minus sign. In other words, the correct identity should be
$$
-\sin(x)=\mp\sqrt{1-u^2}
$$
with the sign chosen based on the value of the input, $x$.

In this problem, $\sin(x)$ is positive from $0$ to $\pi$, but it is negative from $\pi$ to $2\pi$. So the result above could also be derived as follows:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx=-\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{e^{u}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{u}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{u}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$

Comment: How it is possible what u(2π)=−1 ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it. I must have been writing this answer quickly and didn't do the calculation correctly.

Comment: I think you should maybe say more about exactly where the error occurs in writing $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{\cos x}dx=\int_1^1{e^uu\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=0$.  (Hint:  Is it always true that $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$?)

Comment: Okay, that seems like a good idea. Might as well be as complete as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \left(\tan x\right)^3 \Big(\sec^2 x\,dx\Big)
$$
(where you should take the $\Big($Big parentheses$\Big)$  as a hint about what $u$ should be), then you can write
\begin{align}
u & = \tan x \\
du & = \sec^2 x\,dx
\end{align}
and then the integral is
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=\pi/4} u^3 \,du = \left[\frac{u^4}4\right]_{x=0}^{x=\pi/4} = \left[\frac{(\tan x)^4}{4}\right]_0^{\pi/4} = \frac14.
$$
In **this** case, you could say changing the bounds is optional, although it speeds things up and simplifies things:
$$
\int_0^1 u^3\,du = \left[ \frac{u^4}{4}\right]_0^1 = \frac14.
$$

But there are situations in which you'll get nowhere if you don't change the bounds.  For example, the Beta function is defined by
$$
B(\alpha,\beta) = \int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx.
$$
So suppose we have
$$
\int_0^5 x^{\alpha-1}(5-x)^{\beta-1} \,dx.
$$
(I've seen integrals like this arising in statistics problems.)  Then let
\begin{align}
u & = x/5, \\
du & = dx/5.
\end{align}
The integral then becomes
$$
\int_0^1 (5u)^{\alpha-1} (5-5u)^{\beta-1}\,\Big(5\,du\Big) = 5^3 \int_0^1 u^{\alpha-1}(1-u)^{\beta-1}\, du = 125 B(\alpha,\beta). 
$$

Without changing the bounds, how could one recognize this as being the Beta function?